# I am not able to see custom icon on windows task bar but shows default one

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I created installer using wix and able to see the icon on desktop shortcut and control panel, but few of our machines its not showing icon on task bar. Taskbar its showing default windows exe ICOn.

How can I resolve it, bcz in our development machines I am able to see custome ICon on taskbar but testing machine shows default one

```
<Icon Id="GELogo.ico" SourceFile="$(env.installer_icons_dir)\GELogo.ico"/>
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="GELogo.ico" />
```

Even shortcutID also I added

Comment: Locate the application exe => Right click it and hold button => Drag and drop to an empty desktop location and release button => In the menu click "Create shortcut here" => Right click shortcut => Properties => Change icon => Set the icon you want and re-launch application. What icon is in the taskbar? (need to verify). Then comes the WiX part if this works OK.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem where the icon was displayed on some computers but not others. The fix was to change the value of the Icon Id so that it ends with .exe instead of with .ico.

```
<Icon Id="GELogo.exe" SourceFile="$(env.installer_icons_dir)\GELogo.ico"/>
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="GELogo.exe" />
```